# How to use the Vaadin framework Java

Tags: java, vaadin

[image: Screenshot]

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
    content.setSizeFull();
    setContent(content);

    VerticalLayout buttons = initButton();
    content.addComponent(buttons);
    content.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);


    VerticalLayout table = initTable();
    content.addComponent(table);
    content.setComponentAlignment(buttons, Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT);

}
```

Unable to make the UI as in the screenshot. Please tell me how right?

Comment: Which vaadin version? Have you looked into these https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/vaadin-quick-start

Comment: I'd guess you want a HorizontalLayout as content.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your arrows represent moving from view to view.

Reacting to the user clicking buttons, and changing between views, is covered in the tutorials and manuals provided on the Vaadin.com web site. So I will be brief.

To switch views, we could use the new `@Route` feature in Vaadin Flow. I have found that routing feature in Vaadin 14 to be problematic. So I switch views programmatically by my own code, as shown here below.

Using a "Plain Java Servlet" flavor of the [starter app](https://vaadin.com/start/latest) for Vaadin 14.1.2, I change the `MainView` class to look like this. I would also comment out the two annotations `@Route` & `@PWA`, but doing so is raising bugs in this current version of Vaadin, so let's not.

```
package work.basil;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{
    private Button birds, cats, dogs;

    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.removeAll();
        this.add( new MenuView( this ) );
    }

    public void switchToDogsView ( )
    {
        this.removeAll();
        this.add( new DogsView( this ) );
    }
}
```

Let's make that menu view, a set of 3 buttons.

```
package work.basil;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.ClickEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;

public class MenuView extends VerticalLayout
{
    private MainView mainView;
    private Button birds, cats, dogs;

    public MenuView ( MainView mainView )
    {
        this.mainView = mainView;
        this.widgets();
        this.arrange();
    }

    private void widgets ( )
    {
        this.birds = new Button( "Birds" , ( ClickEvent < Button > event ) -> Notification.show( "Birds!" ) );
        this.cats = new Button( "Cats" , ( ClickEvent < Button > event ) -> Notification.show( "Cats!" ) );
        this.dogs = new Button( "Dogs" , ( ClickEvent < Button > event ) -> this.mainView.switchToDogsView() );
    }


    private void arrange ( )
    {
        this.add( this.birds , this.cats , this.dogs );
    }
}
```

One of those buttons calls back to the main view (which never leaves the user's screen). That main view purges its nested menu view, and replaces that content with a new Dogs view consisting of a H1 header and a `Grid`.

```
package work.basil;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.grid.Grid;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.selection.SelectionEvent;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public class DogsView extends VerticalLayout
{
    // Member variables
    private H1 title;
    private Grid < Dog > grid;

    public DogsView ( MainView mainView )
    {
        this.widgets();
        this.arrange();
    }

    private void widgets ( )
    {
        this.title = new H1( "Dogs" );
        this.grid = new Grid <>();
        List < Dog > dogs = List.of(
                new Dog( UUID.fromString( "83f8fd94-1cb6-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125" ) , Dog.Breed.BORDER_COLLIE , "Conan" ) ,
                new Dog( UUID.fromString( "bd9bd346-1cb6-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125" ) , Dog.Breed.AUSTRALIAN_SHEPARD , "Hershey" ) ,
                new Dog( UUID.fromString( "7d1f8f90-a330-49ea-9532-636b9bc6664c" ) , Dog.Breed.SIBERIAN_HUSKY , "Jojo" )
        );
        this.grid.setItems( dogs );
        grid.addColumn( Dog :: getName ).setHeader( "Name" );
        grid.addColumn( Dog :: getBreed ).setHeader( "Breed" );

        grid.addSelectionListener( ( SelectionEvent < Grid < Dog >, Dog > event ) -> {
            Optional < Dog > selected = event.getFirstSelectedItem();
            if ( selected.isPresent() )
            {
                Notification.show( "Selected dog: " + selected.get().toString() );
            } else
            {// Not present.
                Notification.show( "No dog selected." );
            }
        } );
    }

    private void arrange ( )
    {
        this.add( this.title , this.grid );
    }
}
```

We need content for that `Grid`. So here is a `Dog` class. Within this class we define a nested enum for the various breeds.

```
package work.basil;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Dog
{
    public enum Breed
    {
        BORDER_COLLIE, AUSTRALIAN_KELPIE, AUSTRALIAN_SHEPHERD, SIBERIAN_HUSKY
    }

    // Member variables.
    private UUID id;
    private Breed breed;
    private String name;

    public Dog ( UUID id , Breed breed , String name )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.breed = breed;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public UUID getId ( )
    {
        return id;
    }

    public Breed getBreed ( )
    {
        return breed;
    }

    public String getName ( )
    {
        return name;
    }

    // ---------|  Object  |--------------------------------


    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        Dog dog = ( Dog ) o;
        return getId().equals( dog.getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( getId() );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Dog{ " +
                "id=" + id +
                " | breed=" + breed +
                " | name='" + name + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

Run it. We see our three buttons.

[image]

Click the Birds or Cats buttons to see a message appear.

Click the Dogs button to switch views, displaying our data grid of three `Dog` instances. Click any one of them to see a message displaying info about that particular dog, including the `UUID` column `id` not shown in the grid but present in the `Dog` object. Command-click to deselect that same row, and get a message explaining that no dog is selected.

[image]